# undefined reference to 'core:fmt::write' when linking a standalone executable

Tags: debugging, rust, compiler-errors, embedded

I'm trying to implement `core::fmt::Write` for a struct I have written to manage a text buffer in an embedded rust project. I am using `#[no_std]` and my implementation is listed below

```
use core::fmt;
impl fmt::Write for Cell {
    fn write_str(&mut self, s: &str) -> fmt::Result {
        for ch in s.chars() {
            self.put_char(ch)

        }
            Ok(())
    }
}
```

the `put_char` function works properly when used alone. I attempt to use this elsewhere as follows

```
use core::fmt::{Write, Result};
...
let mut buff = io::Cell::new();
write!(&mut buff, "abc");
```

however, when I try to compile this, I get the following error during linking

```
ld: build/main.o: in function `core::fmt::Write::write_fmt':
/rustc/d32c320d7eee56706486fef6be778495303afe9e/library/core/src/fmt/mod.rs:182: undefined reference to `core::fmt::write'
ld: /rustc/d32c320d7eee56706486fef6be778495303afe9e/library/core/src/fmt/mod.rs:182: undefined reference to `core::fmt::write'
```

Why am I receiving this. It appears to reference an issue within the builtin libraries. What am I doing wrong that creates this issue

Do I need to explicitly link against the core libraries? I thought this wasn't necessary

Comment: What command are you using to link your binary? And yes, all Rust projects are expected to link to `core`.

Comment: I'm using `rustc -g -O --target x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu --crate-type staticlib -C panic=abort -C no-redzone=yes -C target-feature=-mmx,-sse,+soft-float --emit obj` to generate an object file that I then link into various other object files by manually invoking `ld`